# How to remove the double quotation from class key to populate event into fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, ajax, fullcalendar

I want to retrieve events ( name, start, end) from sql and display it in full calendar.
The issue is that the retrieved list contains "" arround the key. I want to remove it.

I try static list one time with "" arround the keys and one time without "". The one without "" is working.

This is works

```
function events() {
return [{
        id: 1,
        title: "event1",
        start: "2019-05-03",
        end: "2019-05-03"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "event2",
            start: "2019-05-10",
            end: "2019-05-10"
        },
    ];}
```

This is not works

```
function events() {
return [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "event1",
        "start": "2019-05-03",
        "end": "2019-05-03"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "event2",
            "start": "2019-05-10",
            "end": "2019-05-10"
        },
    ];}
```

I want it dynamically so i wrote:

```
function events() {
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Calendar.aspx/GetData1",
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success:
            function (response) {
                alert(response.d); //it alerts [{"id":1,"title":"TEST","start":"5/20/2019 12:00:00 AM","end":"5/20/2019 12:00:00 AM"}]
                return response.d;
            },
    });
}
```

aspx file

```
$('#m_calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
                },
                editable: true,
                events: events(),
            });
```

So, I need to remove "" from id, start, end keys that retrieved from the ajax response.

Comment: Are you asking how to parse json in javascript? why this question has c# and asp.net tag? ... you know that `events()` returns nothing? ... I would recommend you some javascript basic training

Comment: why the c# tag then ?

Comment: You can escape this in c# by using:  s = s.Replace("\"", "");
For js.  'mystring'.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');

Comment: @Bebolicious 1) I would really hope that OP is not generating their JSON by any kind of string concatenation which would make your suggestion possible, 2) removing the quote marks from the keys will make the JSON invalid. OP is incorrect to state that removing the quote marks is a requirement...their example of code which doesn't work is a) incorrect (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lgz6qvy5/) and b) irrelevant because it uses a JS object literal, not jSON.

Comment: @Selvin because the list is filled in the c# and the callendar viewed in aspx page

Comment: @Kunal Mukherjee because the list is filled in the c# and the callendar viewed in aspx page

Comment: @Alaa did you check my answer below? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see this has nothing to do with the quote marks round the keys. Valid JSON must have quote marks round the keys, that is a requirement of the specification. (Note that this doesn't apply to JavaScript literal objects).

First you claimed that the code:

```
function events() {
  return [{
      "id": 1,
      "title": "event1",
      "start": "2019-05-03",
      "end": "2019-05-03"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "event2",
      "start": "2019-05-10",
      "end": "2019-05-10"
    },
  ];
}
```

didn't work properly. I'm not sure how you came to this conclusion. It works perfectly. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lgz6qvy5/ . However, since this code actually uses a JS object literal and not JSON (please make sure you go and google the difference between these two things!), this example is really not very relevant anyway.

Then you moved on to making your event function make an AJAX call to retrieve the events. This is a good idea of course, but you have a key conceptual problem with what you've written.

You have to bear in mind that AJAX calls are **asynchronous**. The response only arrives within a callback function. That function is executed at some later time from when the request was initiated. The "success" callback function is called by jQuery's code, at the time it receives the response from the server. Therefore, returning a value from that code makes no sense - 1) the value is returned to somewhere in the jQuery code which called the function...that code is not interested in your event data. 2) Even if doing that worked, the actual "events()" function has long since finished executing - due to the AJAX being asynchronous, it didn't wait for the AJAX call to finish before returning.

Luckily, to get round this problem, fullCalendar provides you with a mechanism where you can return the event data to it at the end of an asychronous AJAX request. This is done by providing you with the [events-as-a-function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function) pattern whereby you provide `events:` with a *reference* to a callback function (instead of just the *result* of a function. This function is executed whenever the calendar needs to retrieve events, including when the calendar is first loaded. fullCalendar then supplies the function with a reference to a further callback function which you can call when your AJAX call has completed, and can pass your event data to. When this callback is executed, it adds the data to your calendar.

Here's an example of how you can implement this:

```
$('#m_calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
  },
  editable: true,
  events: events, //note that without the () this is a _reference_ to the function, it does not execute the function immediately
});

function events(start, end, timezone, callback) { //parameters as shown in the documentation
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Calendar.aspx/GetData1",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
      callback(response.d); //run the provided callback function, to pass the events to fullCalendar
    },
  });
}
```

N.B. You should also consider modifying your C# code to accept the "start" and "end" parameters supplied by the callback (and of course modify your AJAX request code accordingly to). The C# would then only return events which occur between the stated start and end dates. This makes the code more efficient because it only returns data which is actually going to be shown on the calendar, rather than returning every event ever added to your database. (If the user ever moves the calendar to a new date where no data has been downloaded, fullCalendar will automatically execute the function again and get the necessary events from the server for the new date range.)

---

P.S. Please also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) which has some good general information about working with asynchronous code such as AJAX.